# Aerodynamic Problem in regards to a ping pong ball and an open hole tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, free-body-diagram, flow, aerodynamics, levitation

I have a ping pong levitation system with a ping pong ball in a tube being pushed by a DC motor fan (shown below) and I'd like to define a relation of the ball's height with the air velocity or airflow. Does anyone know the force effect of a slit on the side of the tube on the pin pong ball?

I know based on research that if the tube was sealed on the side, there is only a drag force applied by the fan going against the ball's weight, but with the slit on the side, I don't know how exactly it's impacting the motion physically. I believe it may be related to a decrease in air pressure, but I'm not 100% sure?? The setup and what I believe FBD of the system have currently been attached. Does anyone know how to represent the unknown force made by the slit.

[image: Physical System]

[image: Assumed Free Body Diagram]